# Different result with roc_auc_score() and auc()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have trouble understanding the difference (if there is one) between `roc_auc_score()` and `auc()` in scikit-learn.

Im tying to predict a binary output with imbalanced classes (around 1.5% for Y=1).

#### Classifier

```
model_logit = LogisticRegression(class_weight='auto')
model_logit.fit(X_train_ridge, Y_train)
```

#### Roc curve

```
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(Y_test, clf.predict_proba(xtest)[:,1])
```

#### AUC's

```
auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
Out[490]: 0.82338034042531527
```

and

```
roc_auc_score(Y_test, clf.predict(xtest))
Out[493]: 0.75944737191205602
```

Somebody can explain this difference ? I thought both were just calculating the area under the ROC curve. Might be because of the imbalanced dataset but I could not figure out why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`AUC` is not always **area under the curve** of a `ROC` curve. Area Under the Curve is an (abstract) area under **some** curve, so it is a more **general** thing than `AUROC`. With imbalanced classes, it may be better to find AUC for a precision-recall curve.

See sklearn source for `roc_auc_score`:

```
def roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average="macro", sample_weight=None):
    # <...> docstring <...>
    def _binary_roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, sample_weight=None):
            # <...> bla-bla <...>
    
            fpr, tpr, tresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_score,
                                            sample_weight=sample_weight)
            return auc(fpr, tpr, reorder=True)
    
    return _average_binary_score(
        _binary_roc_auc_score, y_true, y_score, average,
        sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

As you can see, this first gets a roc curve, and then calls `auc()` to get the area.

I guess your problem is the `predict_proba()` call. For a normal `predict()` the outputs are always the same:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score

est = LogisticRegression(class_weight='auto')
X = np.random.rand(10, 2)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
est.fit(X, y)

false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y, est.predict(X))
print auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
# 0.857142857143
print roc_auc_score(y, est.predict(X))
# 0.857142857143
```

If you change the above for this, you'll sometimes get different outputs:

```
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y, est.predict_proba(X)[:,1])
# may differ
print auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
print roc_auc_score(y, est.predict(X))
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing the importance of the precision-recall curve, but in this case the curve is the ROC. The question was: why am I obtaining two different results since both methods *should* calculate the same area ?

Comment: Why should they? It all depends on how you got the input for the `auc()` function. Say, sklearn suggests `fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred, pos_label=2); metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)`, and then it's natural that `auc()` and `roc_auc_score()` return the same result. But it's not clear how you got `false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate` from your post.

Comment: By the way, I like the ROC curve precisely because it's insensitive to imbalenced classes (see (http://fastml.com/what-you-wanted-to-know-about-auc/)

Comment: My bad, I copied the wrong line of the code. Now it's fixed, thanks for pointing it !

Comment: You are right. since `est.predict(X)` outputs some binary, it makes no sense to use `roc_auc_score(y, est.predict(X))` .  Writting `roc_auc_score(y, est.predict_proba(X)[:,1])` fixes the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. May I ask which one produces the precision-recall curve? Is it using `predict` or `predict_proba`? For an imbalanced dataset, which one should I plot?

Answer (score 32):

`predict` returns only one class or the other. Then you compute a ROC with the results of `predict` on a classifier, there are only three thresholds (trial all one class, trivial all the other class, and in between).  Your ROC curve looks like this:

```
      ..............................
      |
      |
      |
......|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

Meanwhile, `predict_proba()` returns an entire range of probabilities, so now you can put more than three thresholds on your data.

```
             .......................
             |
             |
             |
          ...|
          |
          |
     .....|
     |
     |
 ....|
.|
|
|
|
|
```

Hence different areas.

Answer (score 24):

When you use the y_pred (class labels), you already decided on
the threshold. When you use y_prob (positive class probability)
you are open to the threshold, and the ROC Curve should help
you decide the threshold.

For the first case you are using the probabilities:

```
y_probs = clf.predict_proba(xtest)[:,1]
fp_rate, tp_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_probs)
auc(fp_rate, tp_rate)
```

When you do that, you're considering the AUC 'before' taking
a decision on the threshold you'll be using.

In the second case, you are using the prediction (not the probabilities),
in that case, use 'predict' instead of 'predict_proba' for both and you
should get the same result.

```
y_pred = clf.predict(xtest)
fp_rate, tp_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred)
print auc(fp_rate, tp_rate)
# 0.857142857143

print roc_auc_score(y, y_pred)
# 0.857142857143
```

Comment: In the case of using `predict` instead of `predict_proba` and, as you said, ending up with choosing a specific threshold .. how the calculation of the `roc_auc_score` would be ? any idea ?

Comment: @Ophilia, just from the docs http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html `roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score...)`, where `y_score` - "Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or **non-thresholded** measure of decisions ". So it will be the same as to compute AUC with `predict_proba()`