# Scikit.learn auc function TypeError

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, typeerror, roc

I am following [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31161137/7807920) to compute the AUC score in my data, but if I try to run the script it gives me back a TypeError.

> TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature
>   matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')

I don't understand, because the `roc_curve` function works fine, so I would expect that the `auc` function should work too.
I'have already checked the `dtype` of my test arrays and they are all `float64`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

the test and prediction sets had shape (N,), but they are required to have shape (N,1) from the function `roc_curve`. 
I solved applying the `Numpy.reshape` function on the arrays.