# Custom scorer for GridSearchCV does not allow to use probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I try to create a custom scorer for `GridSearchCV`. Here is the definition of the function:

```
def custom_auc(ground_truth, probas_):
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(ground_truth, probas_[:, 1], pos_label=1)    
    return auc(fpr, tpr)
```

Then I use it to create a custom scorer, named `my_auc`:

```
# to be standart sklearn's scorer        
my_auc = make_scorer(custom_auc, greater_is_better=True, needs_proba=True)
```

And then, I use this custom scorer in the GridSearchCV:

```
param_grid={'C': np.logspace(-2, 2, 40)}
clf = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(linear_model.LogisticRegression(), 
                                           param_grid = param_grid, 
                                           cv = 10, 
                                           scoring = my_auc, 
                                           verbose=False,
                                           n_jobs=-1)    

best_clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The line where the model is fitted, throws the following error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

The problem is that instead of the probabilities, the predictions (1 or 0) are passed to `custom_auc`. That is, `probas` hold the predictions.

I tested with this, and it worked:

```
 return sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(ground_truth, probas_)
```

I prefer my own scorer instead of the existing `'roc_auc'`, because I want to compute the `auc` score based on false positive and true positive rates as recommended in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31161137/1845408.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

`GridSearchCV` passes just the probabilities for the positive labels (the second column from the `predict_proba` output in case of binary classifier) to the custom scorer(`my_auc` in your case). Hence the `probas_` argument passed to `custom_auc` has a shape `(n,)`, where n is the number of rows. If you change the definition of `custom_auc` as follows, it should work.

```
def custom_auc(ground_truth, probas_):
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(ground_truth, probas_)    
    return auc(fpr, tpr)
```